# Printing a receipt using parallel arrays c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have been given this assignment for a lab project, and I have everything working until it gets to the receipt part. The issues I am having are 1) printing the incorrect menu items ordered, and 2) getting -42........ number for the pricing. I've looked through this several times and have spoken with others in the class. This is where we are ALL having issues. My TA said to use array[array1[counter]] for this section, but it doesn't seem to work. Can you help me focus on where things are seriously incorrect?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int    NUM_MENU_ITEMS = 10;  // num items on the menu
const int    MAX_ORDER_ITEMS = 5;  // max num of items per order
const double DISCOUNT_MIN = 20.00; // min subtotal to get discount
const double DISCOUNT_RATE = 0.25; // disc rate for highest-priced item

                                   // Menu: parallel constant arrays
const string menuItem[NUM_MENU_ITEMS] = {
    "Burger", "Hot Dog", "Chicken Fingers", "Fries",
    "Tots", "Tea", "Coke", "Diet Coke", "Water", "Cookies" };
const double menuPrice[NUM_MENU_ITEMS] = {
    3.50, 2.75, 4.25, 2.50, 3.25,
    1.00, 1.25, 1.25, 0.25, 2.50 };

int main()
{
    // Order: parallel partial arrays of items ordered
    // Each item has an item number, quantity ordered, and total price
    // TODO: declare a list of item numbers
    // TODO: declare a list of quantities
    // TODO: declare a list of item prices (menu price X quantity)
    // TODO: declare other variables as needed
    double total, subtotal, discount;

    // receipt line data
    string recName;
    int    recQty;
    int j = 0;
    double recPrice;

    // print menu
    cout << "MENU:\n" << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << "##  Item             Price\n";
    cout << "--  ---------------  -------\n";
    // TODO: write a loop to print the menu

    int i = 0;
    int itemNumber[NUM_MENU_ITEMS] = {
        0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    while (i <= 9)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << itemNumber[i] << "  " <<
            left << setw(15) << menuItem[i] <<
            right << "  $ " << setw(5) << menuPrice[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }

    cout << endl;

    // get order

    int counter = 0;
    int itemQuantity[MAX_ORDER_ITEMS];
    double itemPrice[MAX_ORDER_ITEMS];
    int itemOrder[MAX_ORDER_ITEMS];
    string itemName[MAX_ORDER_ITEMS];

    do {
        cout << "Enter quantity and menu item number (0 0 to end):\n";
        cout << "Item 0: ";
        cin >> itemQuantity[counter] >> itemOrder[counter];
        itemOrder[counter] = itemNumber[counter];
        itemPrice[counter] = menuPrice[itemOrder[counter]] * 
itemQuantity[counter];
        itemName[counter] = menuItem[itemOrder[counter]];
        counter++;
    } while (counter < MAX_ORDER_ITEMS && itemQuantity[counter] != 0);

    // TODO: repeat inputs until quantity is 0 or MAX_ORDER_ITEMS exceeded

    //{
    //  //TODO: add an item to the order parallel arrays


    //  cout << "Item " << menuItem[i] << ": ";
    //  cin >> itemQuantity[i] >> itemPrice[i];
    //}

    double maxItemPrice = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ORDER_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        if (itemPrice[counter] > maxItemPrice)
            maxItemPrice = i;
    }

    // find the subtotal price
    // TODO: use a loop to calculate the sum of all order prices
    subtotal = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ORDER_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        subtotal = subtotal + itemPrice[counter];
    }

    // discount highest order line by 25% when total > $20
    if (subtotal >= DISCOUNT_MIN)
    {
        // TODO: add a loop to find the maximum item price

        discount = DISCOUNT_RATE * maxItemPrice;
    }
    else
        discount = 0;

    // calculate the total price
    total = subtotal - discount;

    // print the receipt
    cout << "\n----------------------------\n";
    cout << "Item            Qty  Price\n";
    cout << "--------------- ---  -------\n";
    // TODO: use a loop to print the lines of the receipt

    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ORDER_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        recName = itemName[i];
        recQty = itemQuantity[i];
        recPrice = itemPrice[menuPrice[i]];
        cout << left << setw(15) << recName << " "
            << right << setw(3) << recQty << "  $"
            << setw(6) << recPrice << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nSubtotal:            $" << setw(6) << subtotal << endl;
    cout << "Discount:            $" << setw(6) << discount << endl;
    cout << "Total Price:         $" << setw(6) << total << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe your answer will be here https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I'd start by checking all of your input for success or failure. `if(cin >> itemQuantity[counter] >> itemOrder[counter]) { good } else { bad }`

Comment: aside: You may wish to research what a function is to split your logic into small manageable bits

Comment: @UKMonkey I wanted to use functions to help, but we were specifically given instructions to only use arrays and loops, no functions.

Comment: Thank you for the debugging pointers.

Comment: Put a breakpoint after each loop; and inspect all the arrays.  At some point you'll find that the contents of the array doesn't match what you're expecting.  Knowing which array is going wrong and in which loop; you can then put a breakpoint at the start of that loop; and then go line by line in the loop to work out why your array isn't what you expected.   It may seem slow and painful; but you have the advantage that you wrote this code!

Answer (score 1):

In this line in the do while loop:

```
} while (counter < MAX_ORDER_ITEMS && itemQuantity[counter] != 0);
```

you have already incremented counter so your while loop is checking a part of the

```
itemQuantity
```

array that has not been input yet.

Also, here

```
double maxItemPrice = 0;
for (i = 0; i < MAX_ORDER_ITEMS; i++)
{
    if (itemPrice[counter] > maxItemPrice)
        maxItemPrice = i;
}
```

counter is a variable used previously and has not been updated. What is counter representing, and what is i?

And again here,

```
subtotal = 0;
for (i = 0; i < MAX_ORDER_ITEMS; i++)
{
    subtotal = subtotal + itemPrice[counter];
}
```

Counter is still the same as it was left in the do while loop. Here it should be

```
subtotal = 0;
for (i = 0; i < MAX_ORDER_ITEMS; i++)
{
    subtotal = subtotal + itemPrice[i];
}
```

Check array parameters closely and make sure what's written is doing what you want it to do. Best of luck!